# Oracle forms implementing a edit functionality in List Item

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am quite new to Oracle forms. I have been tasked with enhancing a form.  There is a list item which has "New" option in case I want to insert a new record. Now I want to add an edit functionality too, but I do not know how to do it. Any insights will be useful. Please let me know in case I need to provide you guys anything for better understanding.

Comment: If you post the relevant code and what you've tried then that would be helpful for us to better troubleshoot.

Comment: @Will Thanks will .  I just wanting to know the approach.  What should be done. If you can say some steps.  Would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via this way

1.Store the list item values in a table
2. Create a new canvas with data blocks for that table
3. Make necessary privileges for the data block like (Update/Delete etc..)
4. In the main canvas ensure that you pass to data block canvas for edit options

P.S: Ensure Form level commits are present such that everything gets committed properly